# I want to load the saved values in json file to textbox in c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to load saved values in json file to textBox.

I already set value in textBox for example 5, so even I change the value in textbox and save to json like 12 or something else, the values always appear the first value 5 when I reopen the winform.

I made this code :

```
private void SettingUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadJson();
}

private void LoadJson()
{
    string jsonFile = File.ReadAllText(@"~~.json");
    dynamic loadFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonFile);
}
```

and I save json file like this :

```
private void SaveValuesToJson()
{
    var json = new
    {
        LiftMax = Convert.ToDouble(radTextBox_LiftMax.Text),
    };

    string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(@"~~.json", strJson);

}
```

If I save 12 in LiftMax, and when I reopen the project, my expectation value will be 12 not 5.

What should I add in codes?

Comment: I think I have to read the json file, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: How have you tried to deserialise it?

Comment: @bolkay I used DeserializeObject, but what should I do when if I want to know specific value for example LiftMax

Comment: Given `var deserialized = DeserializeObject<LiftPositioner>(liftPositionerJson);` worked, you get the correct value in `deserialized.LiftMax`

Comment: I solved to make a class

Answer (score 0):

To work, I made a class like :

```
internal class Item
{
    public double LiftMax { get; set; }
}
```

Then replace the code in LoadJson() :

```
Item item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(jsonFile)
radtextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(item.LiftMax);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a response model

```
internal class Item
{
    public double LiftMax { get; set; }
    public string LiftMaxText => LiftMax.ToString();

}
```

and

```
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(jsonFile)
radtextBox.Text = item.LiftMaxText;
```